# AssertionError: PORT is not a number (in Python)

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, mysql-python, ssh-tunnel

when i using ssh tunnel to access mySQL db, why always show this error on **remote_bind_address** ?

```
AssertionError: PORT is not a number
```

here is my code :

```
with SSHTunnelForwarder(
        (self.ssh_host, self.ssh_port),  # Remote server IP and SSH port
        ssh_username=self.ssh_username,
        ssh_private_key=self.ssh_pkey,
        remote_bind_address=(self.host_mysql, self.port_mysql)
        ) as server:
        server.start()  # start ssh sever
        print('Server connected via SSH') 
        local_port = str(server.local_bind_port)
```

anyone can help me ? thanks before

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Right now, we have no idea what `self.port_mysql` is.

Comment: …including the **full** error traceback.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the error occurs because the port you provide is of type string and not int. Check it by printing `type(self.port_mysql)` before the problematic line.